# How can I make JSON responses be pretty-printed when using Rook?

Tags: clojure, cheshire

I am using Rook framework for web services.  I want to make API responses be pretty-printed.  It seems that the response encoding is all handled by the `wrap-restful-format` function from `ring.middleware.format`.  So I tried to replace the `rook/wrap-with-standard-middleware` function with my own version that passes different options through to `ring.middleware.format`.

```
(defn make-encoders-seq []
  [(ring.middleware.format-response/make-encoder
    (fn [s]
      (json/generate-string s {:pretty true}))
    "application/json")])

(defn wrap-with-standard-middleware-modified
  [handler]
  (-> handler
  (ring.middleware.format/wrap-restful-format :formats [:json-kw :edn]
                          :response-options
                          [:encoders (make-encoders-seq)])
  ring.middleware.keyword-params/wrap-keyword-params
  ring.middleware.params/wrap-params))

(def handler (-> (rook/namespace-handler
        ["resource" 'my-app.resource])
         (rook/wrap-with-injection :data-store venues)
         wrap-with-standard-middleware-modified))
```

This compiles fine but it doesn't work to pretty print the responses, it seems like the custom encoder is never called.

- Rook 1.3.9
- ring-middleware-format 0.6.0
- cheshire 5.4.0 (for `json/generate-string` in above)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change your format/wrap-restful-format to:

```
(ring.middleware.format/wrap-restful-format :formats (concat (make-encoders-seq) [:edn])
```

Comment: Perfect.  Any idea why this works?  I wasn't able to see where it is documented that the value for `:formats` can contain encoders as well as keywords.

Comment: I just read the source code of ring-mw-format https://github.com/ngrunwald/ring-middleware-format/blob/release-0.6.0/src/ring/middleware/format_response.clj#L374. See how if the `format` is a map, it will just use it as it is.